# How do I get a Blue background color for a selected cell in a TTTableViewController?

Tags: ios4, three20

I have the most simple version a TTTableViewController, but can't get a blue background on a tapped cell.
How do I do that?

The following doesn't work:

```
- (UITableViewCellSelectionStyle)tableSelectionStyle {
    return UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
}
```

P.s. Why is it so hard to find any documentation on three20 stuff. It's just getting rediculous now. An API is NOT documentation. It's just a list of the nuts & bolts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it !!!

I needed to set the URL of my tableItem to @"" instead of nil.